# Failed to load plugin 'vue' declared in 'package.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, vue.js, eslint

```
Failed to load plugin 'vue' declared in 'package.json': Package subpath './lib/rules/array-bracket-spacing' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\<my_username>\FolderX\Subfolder\<appname>\eslint\package.json
Referenced from: C:\Users\<my_username>\FolderX\Subfolder\<appname>\package.json
```

That's the error I'm getting every time I `npm run serve` I've upated eslint, added prettier and fixed most of my vulnerability problems, and it still persists. I've combed the eslint issues on github and there is nothing like this, some issues are similar but they refer to eslintrc. Nothing is matching this exactly. I should mention that the app itself is very small and simple. It was supposed to be the start of a project but when I was adding views to the project, this happened.

package.json

```
  "name": "online-birth-registration-system",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've had the same issue after auditing with npm using `npm audit fix --force`. Did you do something similar?

Comment: Yeah I did that very same thing. Maybe it didn't take well to that command.

Comment: This breaks dependencies for other dependencies resulting in broken packages (read more at https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/ ). I have no solution for this other than manually editing node_modules which is insane since `npm install` would revert that completely.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue with `array-bracket-spacing` and was able to fix it by downgrading eslint in my `package.json` from `"^8.6.0"` to `"^7.32.0"`.  None of the other suggested fixes worked for me either

Answer (score 2):

Upgraded `eslint-plugin-vue` to `9.1.1`

Solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the version of the eslint-plugin-vue package that you have installed. Make sure that you are using a compatible version of the plugin with the version of ESLint that you are using. You can check the version of ESLint by running the following command:

```
npm list --depth=0 eslint
```

Then choose the correct version of eslint和eslint-plugin-vue!!!